# PCI Compliance and One-Way Hash function for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, encryption, pci-compliance

I'm hoping someone with experience in PCI compliance and programming could provide some advice. According to this document [PCISecurityStandards](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf) you can save credit card, such as PAN, in a database if you use a one-way hash function. You might also display the information to selected individuals.

Examples of one-way hash functions that I can use in Asp.net are MD5, SHA-512, etc. 
The SHA-512 is a one way encryption (to my knowledge), meaning that I will not be able to decrypt the information for processing. I don't think EAS is a one-way hash function, right?

Is there another type of one-way hash function that I can use that I will be able to decrypt so it can be processed? Does someone have a suggestion?

Comment: "Encrypting" and "hashing" are two completely different things.  A (one-way) hash is just like a fingerprint.  You use an algorithm like SHA512 or (deprecated) MD5to generate a "hash".  This is used to *verify* data.  For example, passwords are stored hashed.  You cannot reverse a hash, but you can verify whether the person typed in the same password.  Encrypting uses different algorithms, like AES, to protect data with a key or password.  Encrypting is two-way, hashing is not.

Comment: What might "EAS" be?

Comment: All storing a hash of a credit card would do is let you verify that the user entered the same credit card that he had before.  A hash is not reversible.

Comment: A misspell, I meant AES.

Comment: AES is a good way to go if you NEED to store your customers' CC numbers.  But you should try to store them offline if you can.  Certainly the key should not be stored on the server.  Better is to have one pass phrase, key file, or whatever of that sort offline, then put it and a salt (stored with and unique to each CC number) into a DeriveBytes method only at the moment you need to decrypt that particular CC number.  A hash is not reversible and, while extremely useful in general, sounds like the wrong tool for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a one-way hash function is not reversible.  That's what the "one way" part means; you cannot decrypt the data that was sent to it.